# Pull-down shelf in cabinet

Tags: kitchens, shelving, storage

I have a small kitchen and the uppermost cabinet shelves are inaccessible without a stool.  Ready-made pull-down shelves are simply too expensive, so I'd like to build my own.

What kinds of hardware should I be looking for (how would I recognize it when searching catalogs or the web), how hard is it to install, and are there any tips for doing it better/more easily?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Product recommendations are off-topic here, so you should reword your question to tackle a specific problem with building your own shelves

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. "Does anyone have experience?" is not a valid question for SE.

Comment: The OP is asking for assistance in building not product information. More information on the type of shelf shelf would be helpful.

Comment: Rephrased to ask specific how-to question. If I didn't capture the intent correctly, please revert the change and post something better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider building one of these as out of the scope of even my abilities, and I have access to a full machine shop / prototyping facility and own almost every tool known to man. The intricacies of these articulating mechanisms, which must be extremely robust to handle the forces involved, and which probably have highly tensioned springs inside them, would put me off to even attempting this.

Comment: I'd consider it if I could find a kit that provided the mechanism. I know kits exist to lift stand mixers from under counter storage to operating height, which is a very similar problem. I haven't seen pull-down hardware offered, but I haven't gone looking for it either.